# new operator on parenthesis wrapped function(IIFE)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I got following code by applying some modification on the compiled version of typescript code of a demo class.

```
function f() {
    function Demo() {
        console.log("Inside constructor");
    }
    return Demo;
}

var Demo = (f)();
console.log("Creating instance");
var demo = new Demo();

// Output
// Creating instance
// Inside constructor
```

After removal of [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) I got,

```
function f() {
    function Demo() {
        console.log("Inside constructor");
    }
    return Demo;
}

var Demo = f;
console.log("Creating instance");
var demo = new Demo();

// Output
// Creating instance
```

In the first case, the constructor executed on the invocation of Demo. In the second case, invoking Demo did not execute constructor. How does `new` operator behaves in each cases?

Comment: It is not about `new` keyword, it is about `var Demo = (f)();` vs `var Demo = f;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var Demo = (f)();` is the same as `var Demo = f();`. You **call** `f` and assign the return value (the Demo function) to `Demo`).

`var Demo = f;` assigns the f function to `Demo`.

The `new` Operator behaves the same way, you are just applying it to different values.

---

> After removal of IIFE

There's no IIFE here at all.

An IIFE is where you have a function expression (you have only function declarations) and you immediately follow it with `()` to call it.

You have a function (`f`) which you either call or don't call.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't remove an IIFE, you simply removed a function call (turning `f()` into `f`).

A correct transformation would look more like:

Original code:

```
function f() {
    function Demo() {
        console.log("Inside constructor");
    }
    return Demo;
}

var Demo = f();
```

Inline `f`:

```
var Demo = (function f() {
    function Demo() {
        console.log("Inside constructor");
    }
    return Demo;
})();
```

Inline `Demo` (to reduce `f` to a single expression for the next step):

```
var Demo = (function f() {
    return function Demo() {
        console.log("Inside constructor");
    };
})();
```

Remove IIFE (i.e. turn `function () { return ...; }()` into `...`):

```
var Demo = function Demo() {
    console.log("Inside constructor");
};
```